# How to divide amount automatically to complete the given target; if someone is on the leave

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In month of January we have 9 workers "cris=200,john=200,bob=200,stev=200,david=200,michle=200,toney=200,jack=200 & sese=200" so fixed target for them in every month is 1800. but in second month "David" is on vacation & we manually divide his target on others so its 225*8=1800. so what is the best formula to use in this situation to divide automatically amount b/w others in future. if again some of them will be on leave how the target will be equally devide on other remaining workers.

Comment: could you write down the complete Formula Please.

Comment: PLEASE HELP ME I STUCK HERE MORE THAN TWO DAYS TO FIND THE FORMULA WHICH AUTOMATICALLY CALCULATE THE AMOUNT B/W OTHERS IS SOME OF THEM IS NOT AVAILABLE. BUT TARGET RESULT SHOULD BE SAME

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Commenting your question in all caps won't help you to get the answer. If you expect the others to give you a ready-to-go solution just because you need it - you're doing it wrong. In other words:
- If you demonstrate at least some effort to solve your problem and give as much info as you have - you have chances to get the solution or at very least some hints;
- If you scream in all caps and only repeat "Give me the formula" - you will not get anything but downvotes.

Comment: yeah you are right but here we are working to CAPS Letters. so sorry for that. but really i am too much worried about to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cell A1 = **cris**
cell B1 = **john**
cell C1 = **bob**
cell D1 = **stev**
cell E1 = **david**
cell F1 = **michie**
cell G1 = **toney**
cell H1 = **jack**
cell I1 = **sese**
```

and

```
cell J1 = **cris**
cell K1 = **john**
cell L1 = **bob**
cell M1 = **stev**
cell N1 = **david**
cell O1 = **michie**
cell p1 = **toney**
cell q1 = **jack**
cell r1 = **sese**
```

now A to I is your worker availability to allocate work. If anyone leave just leave it blank otherwise any characters / numerals

then add the below formula to the cell j2

```
=IF(A2<>"",1800/COUNTA($A$2:$I$2),"")
```

and select the cells J2 to R2 and press CTRL + R

Hope you looking for this?

Comment: Yeah boss it's correct & how can I mark it .. and boss I have one more question... if david earn 100$ & the target for him is 200$ as same for others but after 100$ he quite so how can I devide other 100$ to others & also I have to show david earnings. Please help me also in this case becasue befor we just completely devide his amounts to others but in this situation what we have to do. Will be very thankful to you for your help.

Comment: Boss I am just waiting for your help

Comment: please reply me if you have any idea

Comment: what you want exactly

Comment: Boss actually my question is same I as I asked above  target is given as 1800 but last time we said tha if some one on leave so how his target devide to others bt this time hr work for some days & he earns 100. So now we also have to show his amount an his other remaining amount we have to devide on others.

Comment: No boss I'm using same excel.

Comment: just give a try to work logic is same but based on hour

Comment: Can you assign a formula as you help me before

Comment: Boss did you find out the formula?